# Can't get this color box to stay inside other box and float right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know I'm bad @css but I just can't figure this one out. How do I get this color box to sit nicely right of the word "Orange" inside that longy box?
It keeps looking like this:
[image]

Styles:

```
.color-box {
    float: right;
    border: 1px; 
    overflow:hidden;  
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
border-radius: 4px; 
}


 .box {
    border:2px; 
    border-style:ridge; 
    border-color:#e6dddd; 
    padding: 8px;

  }


<div class="box">
    {{ data.variant[0] }}&nbsp; &nbsp; {{ data.variant[1] }}
    <p class="color-box" [style.backgroundColor]="data.variant[1] == 'Black' ? '#282828' :  '#FF4500' 
"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: simple example - `position: absolute` for `color-box` and `position: relative` for `box`

Comment: nah, that takes it out of the box completely and sits it on top of "Quantity"

Comment: Because the absolute block requires additional css rules. Such as top, bottom, right.

Comment: yeah it will sit everywhere with those just not IN the box :)

Comment: If you have positioned box relative then the color-box absolute plus positioning should put it inside the box as @s.kuznetsov recommends. Can you update your code to a working snippet so we can see the problem.

Comment: I tried running it, and it doesn't work.
Maybe you're using a library?

Comment: yea, maybe because it's inside a Angular Mat pop-up box. Anyway, I switched out the <p> tag of color box for a <div> and was able to position it like that using @s.kutznetsov method. Thanks!

Comment: @doctorprofessor I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but just using `<input type='color'>` will give you a color picker.